# Is there a way to create this Floating Labels Form in Flutter?

Tags: html, css, flutter, codepen

Good Evening everybody, I am trying to create the shared Floating Label type UX in flutter but I am having a lot of problem, getting the things right. Here is something that I have tried and couldn't get past it;

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 10.0),
      child: TextField(
        style: const TextStyle(height: 1.25),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 14.0,
            vertical: 20.0,
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            borderSide: const BorderSide(
              width: 3.0,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          label: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6, horizontal: 14),
            child: Text(
              widget.textFieldLabel,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          floatingLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 2.0,
              color: Colors.grey.shade400,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

As a beginner in flutter I have tried everything and have been stuck at this for the past 2 days. Here is the codepen url: https://codepen.io/JonLehman/pen/JjYZVwO

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically already there. Given that you are using a `StatefulWidget` since you need to update state, add a variable to keep track of your focus:

```dart
bool isFocused = false
```

then wrap your `TextField` inside a `Focus` widget as so:

```dart
bool isFocused = false;
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 10.0),
    child: Focus(
      child: TextField(
        style: const TextStyle(height: 1.25),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: ...
          focusedBorder: ...
          label: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: isFocused ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent), // Changed here
            padding: ...
            child: Text(...),
          ),
          ...
        ),
      ),
      onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
          setState(() => isFocused = true);
        } else {
          setState(() => isFocused = false);
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
}
```

This way, whenever it is not focused, the text will have a transparent background, but as soon as your focus on it, it'll change to a black background.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Example gif]